# Checking for multiple values in a cell to output multiple texts in another

Tags: excel, vba

cell `A1` = `10,21,34,23,45,67`

Need a formula in cell `A2` that does the following:

Check if `A1` contains 10, if yes, then "Coca Cola"
Also check if `A1` contains 21, if yes, then *append* "Pepsi"
Also check if `A1` contains 34, if yes, then *append* "7Up"
Also check if `A1` contains 23, if yes, then *append* "Sprite"
Also check if `A1` contains 45, if yes, then *append* "Fanta"
Also check if `A1` contains 67, if yes, then *append* "Gatorade"
Also check if `A1` contains 99, if yes, then *append* "Red Bull"
...
And so on.

So the output of cell `A2` for the example values above would be something like:

`Coca Cola , Pepsi , 7Up , Sprite , Fanta , Gatorade`

Note that the output values are separated by a `" , "` (i.e. `<space> comma <space>`)
Is this possible as a formula in 1 cell?  There are about 20 values to check for.

Comment: I believe that doing it with a formula would require multiple `Find`/other array-based formulas that would get messy quickly. There is a quick solution with VBA - is that an option?

Comment: my knowledge is very limited. if there is a clear explanation of what to do, sure.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only practical way is with a User Defined Function (`UDF`)

To set it up, put your list of value, string pairs somewhere in your workbook (for this example, I'll use `G1:H7`), values in first column, strings in the second.

Put this code in a module

```
Function ListRange(rValues As Range, rLookup As Range) As String
    Dim ListOfValues() As String
    Dim OutputList() As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim v As Variant

    ListOfValues = Split(rValues.Value, ",")
    ReDim OutputList(LBound(ListOfValues) To UBound(ListOfValues))
    j = LBound(ListOfValues)
    For i = LBound(ListOfValues) To UBound(ListOfValues)
        v = Application.VLookup(Val(ListOfValues(i)), rLookup, 2, 0)
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            OutputList(j) = v
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    If j = 0 Then
        ListRange = ""
    Else
        ReDim Preserve OutputList(LBound(OutputList) To j - 1)
        ListRange = Join(OutputList, " , ")
    End If
End Function
```

Call it like this

```
=ListRange(A1,$G$1:$H$7)
```